# OS X Calendar - view shared Google calendars

Tags: macos, calendar, google-calendar, caldav

I've been able to add a Google Calendar (CalDAV) account to OS X Calendar (v6, Mountain Lion 10.8.5) without problem, and all my own calendars show up.

Is there a way of seeing calendars others have shared with me (these show up under 'Other Calendars' in the Google Calendar website settings)?

(Same situation on my iPhone.)

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Yes, this question is answered by google here:

https://www.google.com/calendar/syncselect

You can click on the link and select shared calendars you wanna sync with your device.

Comment: you're welcome. i just had the same problem few days ago. :)

Comment: I tired your solution, but it does not seem to be working. How long does this change take to take affect?

Comment: I just tried it and it works perfectly. How long it takes depends on how often Calendar.app refreshes. I have it at 15 minutes, but you can force refresh with ⌘R.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Calendar Program like Informant for macOS. it allows you to combine numerous calendars into a single app.