# Add shared Google Calendar to iCloud Calendar

Tags: icloud, calendar, ical

Somebody shared a public Google Calendar with me. I would like to add this calendar to my iCloud account, but I can't find the way to get the iCal address of this Google Calendar.

I looked at the following solution, but the option to display a public iCal is no longer there...

[How to add a Google calendar shared with me, to my iCloud calendars](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282300/how-to-add-a-google-calendar-shared-with-me-to-my-icloud-calendars)

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/106947/os-x-calendar-view-shared-google-calendars

Comment: This is a different question. This tool allows you to add google calendars to any app. I want to share this google calendar to my icloud account, which I don't think is possible with this syncselect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a Google calendar shared with me, to my iCloud calendars](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/282300/how-to-add-a-google-calendar-shared-with-me-to-my-icloud-calendars)

Comment: Yes this is why I quoted this question, but the proposed answer is, to my knowledge, not available anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Subscribe to the calendar via a Google account, then in Google Calendar settings, you can get the iCal-formatted address. You can then add that address to your iCloud, iOS, or Mac Mail app directly with no need to add or sync your Google account.

---

Google Calendar > Settings

In the sidebar, you will see individual settings for each calendar, under the sections *Settings for my Calendars* and *Settings for other Calendars*.

Click on a Calendar. You will see the *Integrate calendar* settings. This will list the Calendar ID, Public URL, etc.

It will also display the iCal-formatted URL as one of either:

> - Secret address in iCal format
> - Public address in iCal format

For example, the public calendar of a [random YMCA](https://www.ymcatoledo.org/google-calendar/dick-family-ymca/):

```
Calendar ID
c_kuc1np2je9ghgq57jr0mfq8b48@group.calendar.google.com

Public URL to this calendar
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=c_kuc1np2je9ghgq57jr0mfq8b48%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=America%2FLos_Angeles
Use this URL to access this calendar from a web browser.

Embed code
<iframe src="https://calendar.google.com/calendar/embed?src=c_kuc1np2je9ghgq57jr0mfq8b48%40group.calendar.google.com&ctz=America%2FLos_Angeles" style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
Use this code to embed this calendar in a web page.

Public address in iCal format
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/ical/c_kuc1np2je9ghgq57jr0mfq8b48%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic.ics
Use this address to access this calendar from other applications.
```